# How to specify different BootstrapperPackage-s for x86 and x64 platforms?

Tags: clickonce

In my WPF project I use some third-party platform-specific dlls, e.g. if `Platform` is `x86` then x86-versions of that dlls are copied into `Output` folder, and if platform is `x64` then x64 versions are.

These dlls also require Visual C++ Redistributable. So I need it to be a Prerequisite to be installed when ClickOnce setup runs. The problem is I need only `x64` version of C++ redist for x64 platform, and x86 for x86 platform. But I **cannot** just write

```
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Visual.C++.14.0.x64" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries %28x64%29</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Visual.C++.14.0.x86" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries %28x86%29</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

because `<BootstrapperPackage>` tag doesn't support `Condition` attribute.

It is also impossible to write multiple `<ItemGroup>` tags with `<BootstrapperPackage>`s inside them because Visual Studio turns

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!--common BootstrapperPackages-->
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <!--BootstrapperPackages for x86-->
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <!--BootstrapperPackages for x64-->
</ItemGroup>
```

into

```
<ItemGroup />
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'" />
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <!--All BootstrapperPackages: common, for x86 and for x64-->
</ItemGroup>
```

I cannot include both packages, because on x86 systems the installer of x64 C++ will show an error, and on x64 systems x86 C++ will be installed but it won't be used.

How can I overcome these difficulties and specify different `BootstrapperPackage`s for different platforms?

Comment: You say "I  cannot include both packages, because on x86 systems the installer of x64 C++ will show an error, and on x64 systems x86 C++ will be installed but it won't be used." but did you try? I feel like these packages should already be programmed to run on the appropriate architecture.

Comment: @dee-see I did. ClickOnce installer checks if every package can be installed, and if at least one cannot, it just shows an error. For x86 machine the error is `Unable to satisfy all prerequisites for PROJECTNAME. Setup cannot continue until all system components have been successfully installed. Prerequisite check for system component Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64) failed with the following error message: "Installation of Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64) is supported only on x64 machines."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the `BootstrapperPackage` element in the csproj file supported the `Condition` attribute, it would be applied only at compile time which is probably not what you want.

Unfortunately here you're going to have to modify the ClickOnce Bootstrapper package manifest on your machine (and on all machines deploying this code).

On my machine the manifests for `Microsoft.Visual.C++.14.0.x86` and `Microsoft.Visual.C++.14.0.x64` are located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86\product.xml` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64\product.xml` respectively. (They might also be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` or any other version of the Windows SDK depending on your OS. The build log when you publish your application probably mentions where its copying the prerequisite from.)

In these files you will find a section like this (taken from my vcredist_x64 manifest)

```
  <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
  <InstallConditions>
    <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
    <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
    <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
    <!-- Block install on any platform other than x64 -->
    <FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="AMD64" String="InvalidOS"/>
    <!-- Block install on Vista or below -->
    <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>
  </InstallConditions>
```

This line causes the error:

```
    <FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="AMD64" String="InvalidOS"/>
```

Modify it to

```
    <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="AMD64"/>
```

to skip the prerequisite instead of failing. The vcredist_x86 is configured to be installed on both 32 and 64 bits OS, if you want to force it to be installed only on 32 bits systems add the following line in its `InstallConditions`

```
    <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="AMD64"/>
```

Related reading:

- [`InstallConditions` MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/commands-element-bootstrapper?view=vs-2017#installconditions)
- [ClickOnce Application: Custom Bootstrapper Packages With Separate Installers for 32- and 64-bit Platforms](https://coding4passion.org/2016/10/14/click-once-custom-bootstrapper-packages/)

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely accept the answer as soon as I test it in action, but for now I already have a feeling it is totally correct. Except that I'd like to specify exact architecture for x86: Instead of `<BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="AMD64"/>` something like `<BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel"/>`. I do know `ProcessorArchitecture` is `Intel` for Intel x86 but I don't know if it is so for AMD x86. Do you know if it's true? Otherwise I need to check it somewhere.

Comment: I think `Intel` will do for all x86 architectures but this will need testing indeed.

Comment: Just found an article where all possible `ProcessorArchitecture`s are listed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2017 They are `Intel`, `AMD64` and `IA64`. So for AMD x86 it should actually be `Intel`.

Comment: Thank you once again, it works like a charm :) Well, not really, it would be cool for ClickOnce to be able to take package manifests from the project folder too, but well, Microsoft... I've also checked `ProcessorArchitecture` on x86 VM hosted on my laptop with x64 AMD processor, and it is `Intel`. Not the purest experiment, but it's enough, I think.

Comment: Everyone **PLEASE NOTE**: if you plan adding new folders with your manifests into `packages` folder instead of changing the existing ones, then don't forget to change `ProductCode` in `product.xml` to prevent conflicts (e.g. if you forget to copy your manifests to `packages` folder then the existing ones with the same `ProductCode` will be used. It is especially actual for `Microsoft.Visual.C++.14.0.x86(-x64)`)

Comment: Fun fact: you can type `$ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` in the PowerShell terminal to find your architecture out. It is `AMD64` for x64, and... *drum roll* for x86 it is `x86`, not `Intel` as in ClickOnce.